# How to get SSR?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

Implementing a nextjs 13 app with the `app` directory and the Client and Server Component.

When displaying the source HTML, my body is empty and only contains scripts and JSON.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="__next_error__">
  <head>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills.js" nomodule=""></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js" async=""></script>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-app.js" async=""></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The JSON/script part is after this html and contains the whole page. As you can see, my body is empty, which I would like to avoid for SEO reasons.

When trying with the former manner with a `page`, I have the html displaying correctly in the body in an html tag.

Did I miss something that prevents SSR in nextjs 13?

In my Layout, I have a Client Component that wraps the whole App like that :

```js
<AppWrapper appCurrentLang="{appCurrentLang}"> {children} </AppWrapper>;
```

I don't think it causes the SSR to fail, because even if I add a `<p>` tag on the root layout, it still doesn't display in the body tag in the source.

Here is the first part of the content displayed after the html :

```html
<script>(self.__next_f=self.__next_f||[]).push([0])</script><script>self.__next_f.push([1,"M1:{\"id\":\"./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js\",\"name\":\"\",\"chunks\":[\"app-client-internals:app-client-internals\"],\"async\":false}\nM2:{\"id\":\"./app/providers.jsx\",\"name\":\"Providers\",\"chunks\":[\"app/layout:app/layout\"],\"async\":false}\nM3:{\"id\":\"./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js\",\"name\":\"\",\"chunks\":[\"app-client-internals:app-client-internals\"],\"async\":false}\nM4:{\"id\":\"./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js\",\"name\":\"\",\"chunks\":[\"app-cl"])</script><script>self.__next_f.push([1,"ient-internals:app-client-internals\"],\"async\":false}\n"])</script><script>self.__next_f.push([1,"J0:[\"$\",\"@1\",null,{\"assetPrefix\":\"\",\"initialCanonicalUrl\":\"/posts/teslas-biggest-threat\",\"initialTree\":[\"\",{\"children\":[\"posts\",{\"children\":[[\"postURL\",\"teslas-biggest-threat\",\"oc\"],{\"children\":[\"\",{}]}]}]},null,null,true],\"initialHead\":[\"$\",\"title\",null,{\"children\":\"My TEST Next.js App\"}],\"children\":[[],[[\"$\",\"link\",\"0\",{\"rel\":\"stylesheet\",\"href\":\"/_next/static/css/app/layout.css?ts=1676839989010\",\"precedence\":\"high\"}]],[\"$\",\"html\",null,{\"lang\":\"en\",\"data-test\":\"test\",\"children\":[\"$\",\"body\",null,{\"children\":[[\"$\",\"p\",null,{\"children\":\"okkk\"}],[\"$\",\"@2\",null,{\"langHeaders\":\"fr-FR\",\"children\":[\"$\",\"@3\",null,{\"parallelRouterKey\":\"children\",\"segmentPath\":[\"children\"],\"hasLoading\":false,\"template\":[\"$\",\"@4\",null,{}],\"notFound\":[\"$\",\"div\",null,{\"style\":{\"fontFamily\":\"-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, \\\"Segoe UI\\\", \\\"Fira Sans\\\", Avenir, \\\"Helvetica Neue\\\", \\\"Lucida Grande\\\", sans-serif\",\"height\":\"100vh\",\"textAlign\":\"center\",\"display\":\"flex\",\"flexDirection\":\"column\",\"alignItems\":\"center\",\"justifyContent\":\"center\"},\"children\":[[\"$\",\"head\",null,{\"children\":[\"$\",\"title\",null,{\"children\":\"404: This page could not be found.\"}]}],[\"$\",\"div\",null,{\"children\":[[\"$\",\"style\",null,{\"dangerouslySetInnerHTML\":{\"__html\":\"\\n            body { margin: 0; color: #000
```

Would anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

It was coming from an server-side error from a library trying to use the `window` object and throwing `ReferenceError: window is not defined`

When removing the lib, the HTML displays perfectly.